XPATH: Quiero seleccionar un elemento de una web que sea único
Necesito seleccionar a través de xpath el elemento que viene resaltada en la imagen, teniendo en cuenta sus padres, para hacerlo único.

Saludos y gracias.

Ya lo encontré. Sería de la siguiente manera:
//div[contains(@class,'slim-select-layer-body')]//div[text()='% Planificado/ Total Ult. año']

